# Simple reverse navigation in datomic

Tags: datomic

Learning Datomic, and having trouble with a basic case. Given a simple schema containing:

```
:club/name
:club/members (ref, cardinality many)
```

and

```
:people/name
```

So it might be populated (basically) like this:

```
[
{:club/name "Carpentry" :club/members [:person/name "liliana" :person/name "alexei"}]}
{:club/name "Taxidermy" :club/members [:person/name "karenna" :person/name "alexei"}]}
etc.
]
```

I want to do a reverse navigation to find "all the clubs 'alexei' is in". If I do this, I get only one club:

```
d/q '[:find (pull ?g [ {:club/_members [:club/name]}]) 
       :in $ 
       :where 
       [?g :person/name "alexei"]
       ]
     (d/db conn))
```

I would expect to get two hits for this example data. Am I modeling it backwards? Do I have to create a separate entity to express person-in-club?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm learning Datomic too, currently, I'm using Datahike because the syntax is similar & easier to dev on imo

Anyway I tried your example and came up with this:

```
(ns club
  (:require [datahike.api :as d]))

(def schema
  [{:db/ident :person/name
    :db/valueType :db.type/string
    :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one}
   {:db/ident :club/name
    :db/valueType :db.type/string
    :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one}
   {:db/ident :club/members
    :db/valueType :db.type/ref
    :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/many}])

(def database "datahike:mem://example")

(def data
  [{:club/name "Carpentry" :club/members [{:person/name "liliana"} {:person/name "alexei"}]}
   {:club/name "Taxidermy" :club/members [{:person/name "karenna"} {:person/name "alexei"}]}])

(comment
  (d/create-database database)

  (def conn (d/connect database))

  (d/transact conn schema)

  (d/transact conn data)

  (d/q '[:find (pull ?e [{:club/_members [:club/name]}])
         :where [?e :person/name "alexei"]]
       @conn))
```

Result:

```
([#:club{:_members [#:club{:name "Carpentry"}]}] [#:club{:_members [#:club{:name "Taxidermy"}]}])
```

Which I think is what you were looking for

There are two things that stand out to me in your comment that might have caused issue:

- Your schema says `people/name` but your data says `person/name`
- The club members vector in your data looks like it's mixing `[` `{` I think you need a vector of two maps in there

But those issues might not be in your source code, could debug further if you'd like to share your source code

Hope this helps

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Turns out it was (mostly) typo, but your suggestions helped me see it. The people/person thing was just a transcription-to-SO error. However, your second observation was the problem: the example vector should have two maps (as your example shows).